# NullPointerException in Java Table Selecting rows

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I am planning to have a table where there is a column that the user will be typing on (the user should enter a number) and everytime he types a number , it will be deducted on the column next to it, say: if I type 2, and the original number is 5, then the column should have 3. But I am having an error. So the first step i thought is to get the selected row.:

this is my FULL exception:

> at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
>       at app.ui.Inventory.getSelectedQuantity(Inventory.java:363)
>       at app.ui.Inventory$2.mouseEntered(Inventory.java:104)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
>       at app.ui.Inventory.getSelectedQuantity(Inventory.java:363)
>       at app.ui.Inventory$2.mouseEntered(Inventory.java:104)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseEntered(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.trackMouseEnterExit(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)

MY TABLE IS NOT SORTED. IT IS JUST PLAIN. BUT I CHANGED THE ROW HEIGHT AND THE COLOR OF THE FONT.

Comment: In ur title of question you have return NullPointer and in question you have written ArrayIndex.... Make it clear.

Comment: Without a full stacktrace and all the relevant code we can't even guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
```

Suggests there is no selected row when your `getQuantity()` method is called. Consequently `tblInventory.getSelectedRow()` will return `-1` causing an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` at this line:

```
String ballID  = dtm.getValueAt(tblInventory.getSelectedRow(),0).toString();
```

Make sure there is a row selected when you do this call.

---

#### Of-topic

See these lines:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblInventory.getModel();
String ballID  = dtm.getValueAt(tblInventory.getSelectedRow(),0).toString();
```

Here `tblInventory.getSelectedRow()` is the selected row number in the ***view*** not the ***model***. If your table is sorted then those indexes will be different causing an unexpected outcome. You have two options:

**Request value to the table**

```
//DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblInventory.getModel();
String ballID  = tblInventory.getValueAt(tblInventory.getSelectedRow(),0).toString();
```

**Convert view index in its respective model index**

```
int row = tblInventory.getSelectedRow();
int modelIndex = tblInventory.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tblInventory.getModel();
String ballID  = dtm.getValueAt(modelIndex,0).toString();
```

See:

- [JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(int viewRowIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)

Comment: still wont work :( i have an exception Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1